# e.preventDefault() doesn't seem to act like it is supposed to

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have a small little widget to show the weather on the sidebar of this page http://jbm.utad.pt/testes/equipa.php

As soon as the document is ready it shoots a city name by AJAX to processa-tempo.php that populates a div in my main page:

```
<div id="exibe-tempo"></div>
```

The accordion is used to show the Forecast and to Choose different cities and here comes the problem. The code is a bit long to post here so I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/jZjQy/1/

It has the jQuery that is inside equipa.php and the markup that processa-tempo.php returns.

If I click in a new city ... it doesn't acts as it is supposed (refresh the div "exibe-tempo")

I really don't know that much to debug this ... any help? it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mmmh i injected `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "processa-tempo.php", data: {cidade:'Lisboa'}, cache: false, success: function(html){ $("#exibe_tempo").html(html); } });` at your page for test case and it worked...are you sure that the click event is fired? ...the fiddle is kinda useless cause the same origin policy :\

Comment: but clicking the city name in the accordion doesn't work! don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your page again and probably found the error. You add the links which containing the cities, dynamically. But the onclick bind comes on page load event. so you have to apply a live listener for this event like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.cidade',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: that instead of     $(document).ready(function(){ or instead of $(".cidade").click(function(event){ ?

Comment: instead of `$(".cidade").click(function(event){`

Answer (score 1):

I checked your site. Here's what I think. Let me know if it works for you.

Your code for click on the cities is defined as below,

```
    $("#cidades").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() :event.returnValue = false;
      ..... });
```

But your links are defined as,

```
    <a href="Penafiel" class="cidade">Penafiel</a>
```

Change your jquery to,

```
    $(".cidade").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() :event.returnValue = false;
      ..... });
```

So that, you bind the click function to each of the  tags instead of the UL which surrounds it. I tried the above code in your site and it works.

Since I am not able to post images--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeRnb.png

Comment: Hey @Sajith S Narayanan ... That was a typo from a different approach I tried ... I already changed to .cidade and put there that jquery line you give me and nothing :(